# PATCH not updating application/json (Python)

Tags: python

I am trying to update home and away score on League Lobster using their API.  When I send the request, I only get the current data back and nothing is updated.

I have searched through all the similar questions with no resolution. The API I am using has this method in its documentation, so I know it supports PATCH. https://scheduler.leaguelobster.com/api/docs/#match-partial_update

[image of API doc showing PATCH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4gns.png)

**My Code** (just want to update home and away score)

```py
import requests

url = "https://scheduler.leaguelobster.com/api/match/113796918"

payload='home_score=1&away_score=3'
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'JWT my_token',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', #Also tried /json
  'Cookie': 'django_language=en'
}

response = requests.request("PATCH", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

**Response** (200 Code)

```py
{
    "id": 113796918,
    "venue_name": "Dads Small Apartment",
    "home_team_name": "Crayon Eaters",
    "away_team_name": "Bad the Sequel",
    "week": 1,
    "start": "2022-06-20T19:00:00",
    "home_score": null,
    "home_points": 0,
    "away_score": null,
    "away_points": 0,
    "friendly": false,
    "comment": null,
    "locked": null,
    "season": 1110234,
    "playoff_fixture": null,
    "home_team": 11547686,
    "away_team": 11547689,
    "venue": 939776,
    "referee": null,
    "assistant_referees": []
}
```

**From the Docs**

```py
HTTP/1.1 200 
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 24 Jul 2022 19:36:17 GMT
Server: openresty/1.15.8.3
Vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept, Accept-Language, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW

{"id":113796918,"venue_name":"Dads Small Apartment","home_team_name":"Crayon Eaters","away_team_name":"Bad the Sequel","week":1,"start":"2022-06-20T19:00:00","home_score":0,"home_points":1,"away_score":0,"away_points":1,"friendly":false,"comment":null,"locked":null,"season":1110234,"playoff_fixture":null,"home_team":11547686,"away_team":11547689,"venue":939776,"referee":null,"assistant_referees":[]}
```

it works with their interaction page but not through Postman or Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are sending the data as form data, but it's expecting a json body. To fix it, its very simple.

Try:

```
payload={ "home_score":1, "away_score": 3 }

headers = {
  'Authorization': 'JWT my_token',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Cookie': 'django_language=en'
}
```

and then

```
response = requests.request("PATCH", url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

Comment: what you suggested was part of it. it also wanted me to close the URL with a / at the end